# In a path connected space, when does every path between $p$ and $q$ induce the same isomorphism between Fundamental Groups based at $p$ and $q$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

Note: I will concatenate paths from left to right.

If $X$ is a path-connected topological space, and $p, q\in X$ are distinct, then any path $\gamma$ between $p$ and $q$ induces an isomorphism between $\pi_1(X, p)$ and $\pi_1(X, q)$, where a loop $\alpha$ based at $p$ is send to the loop $\gamma^{-1}\alpha\gamma$, which is based at $q$. If $\delta$ is another path between $p$ and $q$, then $\gamma$ and $\delta$ would induce the same isomorphism iff $\gamma^{-1}\alpha\gamma$ is homotopic (as a loops with fixed base point $q$) to $\delta^{-1}\alpha\delta$ for all $\alpha$, since these would then be in the same equivalence class and thus equal in $\pi_1(X, q)$. This would only seem to hold if every loop from $p$ to $q$ and then back to $p$ in the reverse direction (i.e., all paths of the form $\gamma^{-1}\gamma$ are homotopic.

Now, this condition is enough to answer the question, but I was wondering if it was equivalent to some simpler condition. I guess it's equivalent to all paths from $p$ to $q$ being homotopic to each other (while fixing $p$ and $q$). Is there a name for this condition?

Comment: If and only if $\pi_1(X)$ is abelian.

Comment: ^Why is that equivalent to any two paths between two points being homotopic?

Comment: Proving what @orangeskid just said is a classic exercise in algebraic topology... you should try to prove it!

Comment: Okay! I'll get to it.

Comment: Wait, is my conclusion that any two paths between $p$ and $q$ are homotopic incorrect? Because $S^1$ has the abelian group $\mathbb Z$ as its fundamental group, but two paths between $p$ and $q$ don't seem to be homotopic if they go around the circle a different number of times.

Comment: Your $p$ and $q$ will induce different isomorphisms if they are not homotopic.

Comment: Wait, but in $S^1$, a loop with is a single run around the circle is not homotopic to a trivial loop, but the fundamental group of $S^1$ is abelian?

Comment: So just to be clear, is it correct that all paths from p to q being homotopic rel {0,1} is a sufficient but not necessary condition for all paths to induce the same isomorphism?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is equivalent to a simpler condition, but not quite the one you're thinking. Suppose you have two paths $\gamma_1, \gamma_2$ from $p$ to $q$. They induce isomorphisms $\phi_1, \phi_2$. Then the automorphism of $\pi_1(X,p)$ $\phi_2 \circ \phi_1^{-1}$ is just the inner automorphism given by conjugation by the loop $\gamma_1 \gamma_2^{-1}$. Note that any element of $\pi_1(X,p)$  can be realized as such a pair of loops (I leave this tothe reader). So for all isomorphisms to be the same, all inner automorphism of $\pi_1(X,p)$  must be trivial, which is precisely when $\pi_1(X,p)$ is abelian.

Answer (score 2):

One might as well state the algebraic result (as in [Topology and Groupoids](http://pages.bangor/ac.uk/~mas010/topgpds.html)):

6.3.2  Let $x, x ′$ belong to the same component of the groupoid $G$. Then $a_*=b_*:  G(x) \to G(x ′ )$  for all $a, b : x → x ′$  if and only if $G(x)$ is abelian.

Comment: @JHance: I've long accepted a maxim of Philip Hall which I learned from Philip Higgins  that one should look for the algebra which models the geometry, and not try to force the geometry unnecessarily into an already given framework. I argue that 1-dimensional homotopy theory is better modelled by groupoids rather than by groups.